# What is the Regular Expression to get all the newline characters from the end of the string

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have tried with `[\s]+$`  and `(?:$|\s)+$`  but i don't get the desired output.

What i am looking for is

```
String str ="this is a string ending with multiple newlines\n\n\n"
```

the new line can be : `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n` depending on OS so we use `\s+` here.

I need to find all the newline chars from end of the string
and i have to use it in Java Code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is that `\s`, in Java, matches any non-Unicode whitespace by default (it matches any Unicode whitespace if you use `(?U)\s`).

You can use

```
String regex = "\\R+$";
String regex = "\\R+\\z";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VxPkl8/1/).

If you need to get each individual line break sequence at the end of string, you can use

```
String regex = "\\R(?=\\R*$)";
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VxPkl8/2).

These patterns mean

- `\R+` - one or more line break sequences
- `$` - at the end of the string (`\z` matches the very end of string and will work identically in this case)
- `\R(?=\R*$)` - any line break sequence followed with zero or more line break sequences up to the end of the whole string.

Comment: Or `$` instead of `\z`, since that's the same thing without the `(?m)` [`MULTILINE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) flag.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, in this case, these are synonyms.